# parallel execution of offlineimap or abuse pythonfile/postsynchook to load second file for account settings

Tags: parallelism, offlineimap

### Why do i need that?

I've set up my dotfiles to include my whole email configuration, but i don't want to share my my private email account settings, so i excluded them.
=> For my mutt/offlineimap i have a "dev account", which settings are fully included in the dotfiles. But i don't want to share at least the rest of my private email addresses publicly.

### possible Solutions

1. just throw all settings in one file (like everybody does) but do `git assume-unchanged`, so that the the settings of the private email address remains private. (just one offlineimap instance) **Problem**: it's just very clumsy to work this way with git and to pay attention every time to make no mistake. **=>** i don't want this.
2. like *1.* but move the private email adresses to an separate file and ignore them with git. (just one offlineimap instance) **Problem**: I don't know how i can set this up, because the only accepted files by offlineimap are `pythonfile` and `[DEFAULT] postsynchook`. Can i somehow abuse them for my needs?
3. parallel execution of offlineimap. **Problem**: When i do it, offlineimap says "Another OfflineIMAP is running with the same metadatadir; exiting."
   *=>* how can i give the second instance of offlineimap another metadatadir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## working Solution

Offlineimap provides an option which lets the user specify which metadatadir the instance should use.

```
[general]
metadata = ~/.dev_offimap
```

With this setting, we can easily manage the simultaneously execution of offlineimap. I just haven't found that in the docs (it's also a bit hidden)